# Java server-side fire Time-Bombs

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, database

I'm facing a problem in which I have a MongoDB, where I storing my data packets. Each data packet has a timed-bomb. I've to execute the bomb at time specified in data packet. Also, these data packets with time bombs will continue to arrive and can have same or different time-bombs w.r.t. other packets.

My task is, at a particular time extract the packets and explode the bomb for the packets timed for that particular time. One way I can think of doing this is: Sort and save packets w.r.t. explode-time as and when they are arriving and repeatedly check if it is time to explode a current packet.

But I'm not sure if I can save packets as and when they arrive based on a field present in them Or I need a different database for this. Also, continuously and indefinitely checking for time will result in system expense.

Can anybody please crack it up for me?

Thanks.

Comment: We need more Time-Bombs!

Comment: hehe, just let me know what sort of :)